# Reorder array for a css multi-column layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, css

how can I reorder an array

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

into..

```
[1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]
```

I need it for a 3-column css layout:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>9</li>
</ul>


ul { -webkit-column-count: 3 }
```

This should produce:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rb
ary = (1..9).to_a
ary.each_slice(3).to_a.transpose.flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

```
slices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].each_slice(3).to_a
zip = slices[0].zip(*slices[1..-1]).flatten
#=> [1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]
```